# App.config or Web.config

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

I'm using httpwebrequest method to call some APIs for data and I want to set value to its timeout property, my goal is to set the value in a config file so that no compiling is needed when the value is reset. I'm not sure which config file is the appropriate one?

Comment: Please provide some code you have written and also please try to be more clear with your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on some **web application**/or need the value on **server side**  then *web.config*, and if  you are working on some **desktop application**/or need on **client side** then *app.config*